# How do I center social media icons within the footer?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to center the social media icons within the footer, but for some reason when I edit the code there is still no change. Can anyone help?

```
footer {
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
}

.fa{
    color: black;
    font-size: 50px;

}

<div class="container">
  <footer>
    <div class="footer-social-icons">
        <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
        <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
    </div>
  </footer>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding `text-align: center` to `footer`?
[image]

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gj2pwb56/)

Comment: @Angel Good to hear. If you can mark my answer as the chosen answer, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You have three options to this:

- If you are using Bootstrap, you can simplay add text-center to your footer calss.
- you can add text-align: center to your footer style.
- You can define the width of a div and then have margin auto to this div, as the following code

```css
.social{
display: block;
width: 20%;
margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="social">
<a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
</div>      
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Symply align your text in the `footer` to center with `text-align: center;`.

```
footer {
  ...
  text-align: center;
}
```

```css
footer {
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.fa{
    color: black;
    font-size: 50px;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <footer>
    <div class="footer-social-icons">
        <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook">F</a>
        <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram">I</a>
    </div>
  </footer>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the help of display: flex property too.

```
.footer-social-icons{
 display:flex;
 justify-content:center;
 width:100%;
 }
```